# Dotnet React Template - is it possible to use /index.html

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps

If I use pure `Create React Application` (without dotnet), then I can open the react application in two ways (after `yarn start`):

- https://localhost:3000/
- https://localhost:3000/index.html

[image]
[image]

But if I use `Dotnet React Template`, then there is only one way I can open the application (when I add index.html, I only see the dotnet part of the app, but not react) after `dotnet run`:

- https://localhost:5001/
- https://localhost:5001/index.html

[image]
[image]

I would like to find a way to use index.html here as well.

Why am I asking. I recently tried adding my site as a Bookmark to iPhone's Home Screen.

It turned out that this doesn't just work as a link, but iOS now interprets those sites as Progressive Web Application. That is, additional requirements are imposed on the site. And one of them is having a working `index.html`.

This is why I would like my Dotnet React application to work properly with `/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get ClientApp/src/App.js and change the first route to below.

```
<Route exact path={['/', '/index.html']} component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Right answer from M. Erim Tuzcuoglu and we can just do it like this:

```
<Switch>    
    <Redirect exact from='/index.html' to='/' />
    <Route exact path='/'... />
    ...
</Switch>
```